# Centered div and fluid left padding over the container

Tags: css, fluid-layout

I have a centered red div (blue) with a max width (1240px) in my layout and I search to make this in CSS. The logo area (purple) from the left of the centering area (blue) is 300px. At the left of this point, in red, it will be fluid (whatever the screen resolution you have).

(btw, that's the same thing for the lightgray div just below)

Do you have an idea to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here, have a look at this one:

http://css-tricks.com/the-perfect-fluid-width-layout/

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/786Sn/1/)**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="logo">
    logo here
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.container{
    width: 1240px;
    background: orange;
    text-align: center; 
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.logo{
    width: 180px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what you mean could you please explain exactly what you need?